# DocumentMetada.plist not complete in iCloud

Tags: ios, icloud

I'm creating a pretty simple iOS app that will have a single UIManagedDocument with a Core Data database that I want to sync via iCloud. When I open the app, I setup the NSMetaDataQuery and get notifications for NSMetadataQueryDidFinishGatheringNotification and NSMetadataQueryDidUpdateNotification. When one of those come in, they call a method that will check and see how many files are in the iCloud documents directory. If there are none, one will be created, and its persistantStoreOptions are set in the following method

```
- (void)setPersistentStoreOptionsInDocument:(UIManagedDocument *)document
{
    NSMutableDictionary *options = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
    [options setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] forKey:NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption];
    [options setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] forKey:NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption];

    [options setObject:[document.fileURL lastPathComponent] forKey:NSPersistentStoreUbiquitousContentNameKey];
    [options setObject:[[self iCloudURL] URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"DataLogs"] forKey:NSPersistentStoreUbiquitousContentURLKey];

    document.persistentStoreOptions = options;
}
```

The file seems like it is successfully created (I can see it listed in the iCloud documents viewer) however, later when I go to open the file, either when restarting the app or opening it on a new device, I have a problem.

I create a new UIManagedDocument, then create its persistentStoreOptions by creating an NSDictionary from the DocumentMetadata.plist file. However, when I look at what's in the dictionary, only the NSPersistentStoreUbiquitousContentNameKey is in there. The code I'm using is:

```
NSMetadataItem *item = [self.iCloudQuery resultAtIndex:0];
NSURL *url = [item valueForAttribute:NSMetadataItemURLKey];
url = [self filePackageURLForCloudURL:url]; // gets top level filename
self.accountDatabase = [[UIManagedDocument alloc] initWithFileURL:url];
NSURL *optionsURL = [self.accountDatabase.fileURL URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"DocumentMetadata.plist"];
NSDictionary *options = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfURL:optionsURL];
self.accountDatabase.persistentStoreOptions = options;
[self useDocument:self.accountDatabase];
```

Is there some step I'm missing that is preventing the rest of the items in the persistentStoreOptions from getting uploaded to iCloud?